# IIS Site not working when i provide hostname

Tags: iis, localhost, iis-10

I am using IIS 10. I am creating a test site and binding with no host name. (Type is http and port is 80). when I access the site using http://localhost/index.html the site is working fine.
[image]

[image]

When i add host name and add the host name in host file, site is not working

Host File entry is : 127.0.0.1  [www.testmylocalsite.com](http://www.testmylocalsite.com)

[image]

[image]

Could you please help me what's going wrong? Also i tried with user permission (IUSR and App Pool user) for the physical directory. But nothing works for me.

Comment: Are you sure you have proxy disabled in your browser settings?

Comment: It was some internal issue @Lex figured it out. Thanks

Comment: Then either you post your own answer to hint others, or simply delete this.